# WPF Infragistics XamDataGrid Stealing Focus on Scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I'm using the Infragistics XamDataGrid inside of a control with a scrollbar. The parent control has several other controls within it, and I need to be able to scroll freely within the parent control. However, whenever the mouse is hovered over the XamDataGrid, the XamDataGrid steals the parent focus and locks up the scrollbar of the parent control.

I've looked into the XamDataGrid [documentation here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v12.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.XamDataGrid_members.html)

And I've played around with several properties. Setting the  `Focusable` property to `false` did not fix the issue. Setting the `IsEnabled` property to `false` worked, but it disabled the entire grid and prevented any interaction with the grid (duh).

Is there a way to remove/disable the scroll functionality of the XamDataGrid to enable its parent element to scroll freely, without changing other functionality of the XamDataGrid (i.e. without disabling interaction with the grid completely)?

**Edit:**

What really intrigues me about this problem is that it does not seem to be isolated to just the XamDataGrid. I've found that Infragistics controls have a thing for stealing focus when they shouldn't and similar meddlesome behavior.

Granted, many of these problems are probably fixable on a control-by-control basis, but I can't shake the feeling that there is some better overarching solution out there, especially when combing through control properties fails to yield the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently XamDataGrid implments a ScrollView which catches the scrolling events, the workaround is to have these events passed to the parent ScrollView via an event handler.

The Infragistics Support has suggested a way to do so:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/107444/506422.aspx#506422